# PHP Date Range According to Today's Date

Tags: php, date-range

Can anyone think of a better way of writing this out in a loop and getting the same result?

```
$today = date('l');

    if($today == 'Wednesday'){
        $min = date('l-m-d-y');
        $max = date('l-m-d-y', strtotime('+4 days'));
    }else if($today == 'Thursday'){
        $min = date('l-m-d-y', strtotime('-1 days'));
        $max = date('l-m-d-y', strtotime('+3 days'));
    }else if($today == 'Friday'){
        $min = date('l-m-d-y', strtotime('-2 days'));
        $max = date('l-m-d-y', strtotime('+2 days'));
    }else if($today == 'Saturday'){
        $min = date('l-m-d-y', strtotime('-2 days'));
        $max = date('l-m-d-y', strtotime('+1 days'));
    }else if($today == 'Sunday'){
        $min = date('l-m-d-y', strtotime('-3 days'));
        $max = date('l-m-d-y');
    }

    echo $min . ' - ' . $max;
```

Comment: What's the goal with the adding / subtracting days?

Comment: @Will I'm creating directories based on dates with files inside that relate to that date... so for instance 08_01_2010 will have file1.html and file2.html while 08_02_2010 will have file3.html and file4.html...  I need the allowed dates to be within a specific range of dates.  So, if it's Wednesday, I need to search for folders up to Sunday, if it's Friday, I need to search BACK to Wednesday and UP to Sunday etc...

Comment: Artefacto looks to have crafted a magic solution for this.  :)  Was thinking along these same lines - calculate the number of days back / forward required and you're sorted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assumed you wanted -3 in the min on Saturday and -4 on Sunday. Anyway, this is the idea:

```
$weekday = date("w");
if ($weekday == 0)
    $weekday = 7;

if ($weekday >= 3) {
    $min = date('l-m-d-y',
        strtotime(($weekday==3?"+0":(3-$weekday))." days");
    $max = date('l-m-d-y',
        strtotime("+".(7-$weekday)." days");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

could store it in an array with the day as the key and the +/-x days as the values.